# What is the type of files I get when downloading the source code of .NET Framework?

Tags: file-extension

I want to download the source code of .NET Framework 4. From [the official website](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx), I get the files with the extension `.aspx`; WinRAR is pretending that those are broken CAB files, and Windows won't open them if they are renamed to `.cab` or `.exe`.

What is the actual type of those files? How to open them? Are they actual files or the website is just broken and sending random stuff?

Comment: `.aspx` files are for ASP.NET web forms development.  Why do you need to open them?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: The actual extension is wrong, since the website is broken (well, not broken enough to give access to its own source, but still broken when it comes to HTTP headers of served files). That's why I'm asking about the actual type of those files.

Comment: What's your actual endgame here.  Are you trying to install .NET 4?

Comment: @KronoS: no. The actual goal is to get the source code of .NET Framework, like I specified both in the title of my question and in the first sentence of the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Those files are MSI packages, so the correct extension would be `.msi`.

Thanks to [the answer by Christopher Currens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118869/240613) to a similar question on Stack Overflow.